# AR Kit 2.0 get the image details of tracked image?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm pretty new to AR Kit but recently I found that the image tracking feature is quite awesome. I found it's as simple as:

```
let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: Bundle.main)

let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.trackingImages = referenceImages
configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1

sceneView.session.run(configuration)
```

which works beautifully! However, I want to further the experience by identifying which image has been tracked and display different AR objects / nodes based on the image that was tracked. Is there a way to get more information on the specific image that is currently being tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you AR Reference Group in your assets catalog, when you click the reference image, you can open the attributes inspector and enter a "Name."

[image: attributes inspector]

This name is then reflected in the `name` property of the `ARImageAnchor` for the anchor that is created when the AR session begins to track that specific image.

Then in

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?
```

You can inspect the anchor and respond accordingly. For example:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let anchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return nil }
    if anchor.name == "calculator" {
        print("tracking calculator image")
        return SCNNode.makeMySpecialCalculatorNode()
    }
    return nil
}
```